# 2 Breaker Box and wiring

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a room addition that is wired to a different breaker box, not the main breaker box. I am putting two 20 amp breakers in because I had 12/2 wiring. Does one give power to other breaker? Or do I need a seperate hot wire in lower connection to breaker?

Comment: What make and model is this subpanel box, and how many wires run to it from the main panel?  Can you post photos of the subpanel box, including its innards as well as the label on the inside of the door, please?

Comment: Are you sure you mean 12/2 and not 12/3 with a shared neutral? (can't use 2 breakers for that, have to use a 2-pole).  12/2 generally goes to a single breaker unless it is supplying 240V.

Comment: Square D 2 Breaker 70 amp max box. Wires running from Parks Mobilehome Breaker Box isn't 12/2. It's much larger than 12/2, Mobilehome is wired with 12/2. I will post a picture in a few minutes. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: 3 wires run from main panel.